# React Native Navigatoin. Запрет перехода назад по стеку

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, navigation

Проблема следующая. Сейчас переход с экрана авторизации на основное меню реализован таким образом -

```
<Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name='MainDrawerNavigator' component={MainDrawerNavigator} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Могу ли я каки-то образом запретить переход назад по стеку (из MainDrawerNavigator обратно в LoginScreen)? Или в данном случае нужна другая реализация навигации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше все таки использовать подход, который рекомендую в самой документации https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

А если исходить из текущего примера (все таки не советую так делать), то можно как-то так (добавил `options` для скрина):

```
<Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false
            }}>
    <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name='MainDrawerNavigator' options={{
        headerLeft: ()=> null, 
        gesturesEnabled: false,
}} component={MainDrawerNavigator} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

плюс, еще сам переход на этот скрин можно реализовать так:

```
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'MainDrawerNavigator' }],
});
```

Comment: Вариант с ```navigation.reset``` сработал, при попытке перейти в начало стека приложение закрывается. На данном этапе этого достаточно. Спасибо за ответ!